# Nested for loops in R - Issue with final result

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested

I am in the midst of solving a problem in Reconstructing (or recovering) a probability distribution function when only the moments of the distribution are known. I have written codes in R for it and although the logic seems right to me, I am not getting the output that I want.

The equation I am trying to using as the approximated (or reconstructed or recovered) CDF is what you see in the image below. I am writing codes for the right hand side of the equation and equating that to a vector that I call F in my codes.

The link to paper that contains the original equation can be found here.

- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715208000187

It is marked as equation (2) in the paper.

Here is the code I wrote.:

```
#R Codes:  
alpha <- 50
T <- 1
x <- seq(0, T, by = 0.1)

# Original CDF equation
Ft <- (1-log(x^3))*(x^3)  
plot(x, Ft, type = "l", ylab = "", xlab = "")

# Approximated CDF equation using Moment type reconstruction
k<- floor(alpha*y/T)  
for(i in 1:length(k))  
{
for(j in k[i]:alpha)  
{  
F[x+1] <- (factorial(alpha)/(factorial(alpha-j)*factorial(j-k)*factorial(k)))*(((-1)^(j-k))/(T^j))*((9/(j+3))^2)
}
}
plot(x[1:7], F, type = "l", ylab = "", xlab = "")
```

Any help will be appreciated here because the approximation and the graph obtained using my codes is grossly different from the original curve.

Comment: FYI, I removed your inline code markdown for the block quote alternative. This can be accomplished by indenting your code block with four spaces, or hitting the `{}` button after highlighting the code you want to indent. Can you double check that I didn't mangle the initial intent of the code?

Comment: It's just about impossible to help you, since your link is not publicly accessible. Thus I have neither your equation, nor your desired results.

Comment: When I run your code I get an error that y is not found.  I guess y is a vector because otherwise is not length of k = 1?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use your own shorthand with the factorials.  I suggest writing them out as expressed in Equation 2 until you get the code to work.  I find that helps me avoid misplaced parentheses.  Not saying you have a misplaced parenthesis.  Just trying to offer a helpful suggestion.  Also, consider defining mu outside of the loops, just to make the code a little easier to follow.  I guess I want to be clear where the 9 came from.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that your problem is in here.

```
F[x+1] <- (factorial(alpha)/(factorial(alpha-j)*factorial(j-k)*factorial(k)))*(((-1)^(j-k))/(T^j))*((9/(j+3))^2)
```

You are trying to get something varying in x, yes? So how can you get that, if the right hand side of this equation has nothing varying in x, while the left hand side has an assignment using non-integer indices?

Answer (score 0):

```
    alpha <- 30  #In the exemple you try to reproduce, they use an alpha of 30 if i understood correctly (i'm a paleontologist not a mathematician so this paper's way beyond my area of expertise :) )

    tau <- 1  #tau is your T (i changed it to avoid confusion with TRUE)
    x <- seq(0, tau, by = 0.001)
    f<-rep(0,length(x))  #This is your F (same reason as above for the change). 
    #It has to be created as a vector of 0 before your loop since the whole idea of the loop is that you want to proceed by incrementation.

    #You want a value of f for each of your element of x so here is your first loop:
    for(i in 1:length(x)){

    #Then you want the sum for all k going from 1 to alpha*x[i]/tau:
        for(k in 1:floor(alpha*x[i]/tau)){

    #And inside that sum, the sum for all j going from k to alpha:
            for(j in k:alpha){

    #This sum needs to be incremented (hence f[i] on both side)
                f[i]<-f[i]+(factorial(alpha)/(factorial(alpha-j)*factorial(j-k)*factorial(k)))*(((-1)^(j-k))/(tau^j))*(9/(j+3)^2)
                }
            }
        }

    plot(x, f, type = "l", ylab = "", xlab = "")
```